# Upload CSV to MySQL and Define Columns

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a form that uploads a CSV file to a DB and it works perfectly fine.  My question is how can I have it so that on the upload form the user has that they can define what the column is.  For instance if I have a form and it has 3 form boxes labeled Name, Phone, ID.  Then on the csv sheet Name is in column B Phone is in column G and ID is in column Z, Have the user input the columns into the textbox.

```
Form:
Name: ____   Phone: ____   ID: ____
```

Here is my current script:

```
<?php
include "../config/config.php";

if (isset($_POST["import"])) {

    $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

    if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {

        $file = fopen($fileName, "r");
        fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",");
        while (($column = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $sqlInsert = "INSERT into users_dept(Name, Phone, ID2)
                   values (
                   '" . $column[0] . "',
                   '" . $column[1] . "',
                   '" . $column[2] . "')


                   ";

            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlInsert);

            if (! empty($result)) {
                $type = "success";
                $message = "CSV Data Imported into the Database";
            } else {
                $type = "error";
                $message = "Problem in Importing CSV Data";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post"
                name="frmCSVImport" id="frmCSVImport" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="input-row">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Choose CSV
                        File</label> <input type="file" name="file"
                        id="file" accept=".csv">
                    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="import"
                        class="btn-submit">Import</button>
                    <br />

                </div>

            </form>
```

Curretly the user just removes the columns and uploads the required ones.  What I would like is a user can define where the columns are and the just upload and the script ignores the columns that are not defined in the user input form.  Then this could be more versatile in what I want and then could also use it for other uploads I am working on without changing it.

Like this image
[image: https://i.ibb.co/cYjr6sg/2019-12-26-14-07-46-Window.png]

Comment: This seems very straightforward. A=0, B=1,C=2, etc. What have you tried?

Comment: Honestly just looking for a jump off point. Some of the sheets have different orders of the column. IE: column A = name on sheet1 where sheet2 column K = name